# google maps : How to find if any markers inside map

Tags: google-maps

I have divided the my google map display in to numbers of parts, Now I want of find it out if any markers are positioned inside a/any particulate cell.

Any Help ?

Farther Explained :

I have got the map bounds by

```
map.getBounds();
```

method and then farther divide it into numbers of sub-bounds.

also I have putted markers as

```
map.addOverlay(markerObject);
```

Now , I want find if of the cells (which I got by dividing the map by bounds) is containing any markers or not .

*I have divide the entire map bounds into numbers of sub bounds*

Comment: please explain how exactly you have divided the map and how do you keep the markers collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So keep all markers in array. Each marker has a method called get_position( ). After you have finished division of map bound into small sub bounds, you just need to iterate over the sub bounds and check whenever the marker within it.

PS. Also take a look on [it](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Marker_Manager), in some cases could be useful.

---

Suppose you on sub bound cell:

```
var sub_bounds = new Array();
// here you've pushed into an array the sub bounds
for ( var i = 0; i<sub_bounds.length; ++i)
{
    for ( var j = 0; j < markers.length; ++j)
    {
       var lat = markers[j].get_position( ).lat;
       var lng = markers[j].get_position( ).lng;
       if ( sub_bounds[i].sw.lat<lat && lat<sub_bounds[i].ne.lat &&
            sub_bounds[i].sw.lng<lng && lng<sub_bounds[i].ne.lng)
       // marker within cell, do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost there , But confuse as 
If suppose I am on a sub-bounds cell then , How can I find that , this cell contains any markers or not?

Comment: does it do the same thing , as 

sub_bounds[x].containsLatLng(markers[i].getLatLng())  ??

Comment: yeap. thank for pointing, I have had to look at API reference better.

Comment: OK thanks,
But I was trying to find it from another way , 
Just have a method for 'sub_bounds' object [ like 'isEmpty();' which returns the area covered by a bound.]

which will return if that bound contains any markers or not , not by looping throw the markers. .... any Idea .

Comment: you know deeply in some dark place someone still have to iterate over the markers to see whenever they within your bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to the above solution **without** re-iteration:

First - how big are your sub_bounds? Say 10 latitude and longitude degrees each.

Second - The position of the marker is (floor(marker.lat / 10), floor(marker.lng / 10))

Third - Each marker is added to the map and dropped in a bucket for that subdomain.

so (40, -78) would lie in bucket (4,7) i.e. bucket["4~7"]

> **Correction:** would lie in bucket (4,-7) i.e. bucket["4~-7"]

which would contain all markers between 40 and 50 lat and -70 and -80 lng.

You can use GLatLngBounds as the object that holds all these markers in each bucket, which would give you a good set of methods to use, such as calculating center of the bucket depending on the markers currently in it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution is given here: how to find out whether a point is inside a polygone:

[How to detect that a point is inside a Polygon using Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036408/how-to-detect-that-a-point-is-inside-a-polygon-using-google-maps)