# How to detect that a point is inside a Polygon using Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, geocoding, google-maps-api-3

I would like to detect that a `google.maps.LatLng` is inside a `google.maps.Polygon`.

How can I do that ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Other solution: [Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon](https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon)

> A Javascript Google Maps v3 extension for the Polygon class to detect whether or not a point resides within it...

Comment: For some odd reason this works but I was never able to get Google's containsLocation() function to work.....

Comment: @WildBill - You'll need the geometry library to get it to work.
Example: ?sensor=false&libraries=drawing,geometry

Comment: I added the geometry library from Google but it still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 22):

You can use this in **google map V3**:-

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),polygons);
```

polygons is a object returned by function after **polygoncomplete**.

```
var polygons=null;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, "polygoncomplete", function(polygon) {
        polygons=polygon;
});
```

reference by https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

Answer (score 5):

Google provides their own implementation within the geometry library, which I haven't checked, but presumably covers the edge cases discussed in the other answers.

See the containsLocation method [described here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#poly).  Note that you will have to [import the geometry library explicitly, as it is not in the base map  API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries.html)

Answer (score 4):

I used this algorithm to detect that the point is inside the polygon : http://alienryderflex.com/polygon/

I added a new method `contains` to the Polygon :

```
// Add a function contains(point) to the Google Maps API v.3

google.maps.Polygon.prototype.contains = function(point) {
  var j=0;
  var oddNodes = false;
  var x = point.lng();
  var y = point.lat();

  var paths = this.getPath();

  for (var i=0; i < paths.getLength(); i++) {
    j++;
    if (j == paths.getLength()) {j = 0;}
    if (((paths.getAt(i).lat() < y) && (paths.getAt(j).lat() >= y))
    || ((paths.getAt(j).lat() < y) && (paths.getAt(i).lat() >= y))) {
      if ( paths.getAt(i).lng() + (y - paths.getAt(i).lat())
      /  (paths.getAt(j).lat()-paths.getAt(i).lat())
      *  (paths.getAt(j).lng() - paths.getAt(i).lng())<x ) {
        oddNodes = !oddNodes
      }
    }
  }
  return oddNodes;
}

google.maps.Polyline.prototype.contains = google.maps.Polygon.prototype.contains;
```

Comment: Very nice, it works. Just change `var x = point.getPosition().lng();` and `var y = point.getPosition().lat();`

Answer (score 2):

Every method described here fails in one way or another.

The methods given by Andrei I and Natim ***do not*** consider polygons with geodesic edges. These methods also fail to realize that a non-geodesic edge in Google Maps is only straight within the Mercator projection. These methods assume the vertices lie on a equal distance lat/lon grid where one degree latitude equals one degree of longitude. As a result of this error, these methods will indicate a point is outside the polygon, while being displayed inside for some cases. This is easily observed for long non-vertical/non-horizontal edges. <del>To resolve this issue, all points must first be converted from Latitude, Longitude to X, Y coordinates in the Mercator projection. [Here is the method to convert the coordinates from lat/lon to x/y in Mercator.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MercatorProjection.html)</del> (Lacks accuracy) [Rhumb line navigation can be used as a basis for an alternative method.](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Rhumb) Google Maps experimental version 3.10 implements this method.

The method mentioned by Paul Gibbs, swapnil udare, and Adi Lester ***does*** consider geodesic edges, but as of Google Maps v3.9 it uses the same method mentioned above for non-geodesic polygons. As such it also suffers from the same issue described above.

**Update** - The issue with Google Maps has been corrected in the current experimental version of Google Maps v3.10.

Answer (score 2):

No need for complex algorithms, I was able to achieve this using isPointInPath() method of html canvas.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_ispointinpath.asp

Create a canvas element. 
Draw a polygon with multiple endpoints using moveTo(),lineTo() methods.
Verify if a point(x,y) lies inside the polygon using isPointInPath() method.

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

//x,y are coordinate of the point that needs to be tested
//coordinates contains all endpoint of a polygon in format of x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3....
function isPointInPolygon(x, y, coordinates) {
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var coords = coordinates.split(',');

if (coords != null && coords.length > 4) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(coords[0], coords[1]);
    for (j = 2; j < coords.length; j++) {
        ctx.lineTo(coords[j], coords[j + 1]);
        j++;
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(x, y))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: The poster was asking about Polygons on Google maps. Not all browsers support canvas and the above method assumes a standard X, Y grid. If one is drawing on a canvas, the above method is perfect otherwise it's just wasteful. The other methods mentioned above can compute this without the overhead of drawing on a canvas. The best method as of Google maps v3.10 is google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation() since it handles geodesic polygons as well as mercator polygons.

Comment: I agree. It does not exactly answer this question but could help people who are working in html5 environment and end up in this post to detect point in polygon. I came to this post and tried implementing all the algorithms but nothing worked perfectly. I basically implemented a custom map on a floor plan image using canvas. I had to show tooltips on different part of image and mimic html image map functionality.